# what is best way to call rest api repeatedly by changing parameter in android

Tags: android, json, okhttp, restful-url

```
[ 11547212, 11546098, 11544988, 11546490, 11543083, 11544016, 11545112, 11545975, 11543258, 11541675, 11544510, 11543188, 11544254, 11544374, 11541702, 11545351, 11542995, 11542005, 11543646, 11540747, 11541834, 11541242, 11544686, 11544523, 11546077, 11543321, 11544010, 11544342, 11541474, 11547035, 11545970, 11544047, 11533500, 11547236, 11541971, 11543798, 11547042, 11542803, 11540825]
```

this is response of webservice https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty here each id contains specific data ,here is service to get data of each item 
    https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/11533382.json?print=pretty
here how to get data of all items, how to call the second url repeatedly,what is the best way to call.

Comment: use a for loop simply.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
 //here is your code...
}
```

or get this JSONArray as String